# STM32L011x3/4 TSSOP14 pinout schematic

Tags: power-electronics, schematics, programming, debugging, programmer

[image]

Can someone who understands the bad subject in english can fix it

schematic where exactly is the error

ST-Link V2 debug programs error

Comment: The schematics should work, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Do you know the schematic, is there an example